# When to use XmlConvert.ToString vs Object.ToString()

Tags: c#

When should I use `XmlConvert.ToString` to convert a given value versus the `ToString` method on the given type.

For example :

```
int inputVal = 1023;
```

I can convert this `inputVal` to string representation using either method:

```
string strVal = inputVal.ToString();
```

or

```
string strVal = XmlConvert.ToString(inputVal);
```

What is the rule for using `XmlConvert.ToString` versus doing plain `Object.ToString`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `XmlConvert.ToString` methods **are locale independent** so the string representation will be consistent across different locales. With `Object.ToString` you may get a different representation according to the current culture associated with the thread.

So using one versus the other is a matter of the scenario, `XmlConvert` lends well if you're exchanging data with another system and want a consistent textual representation for example a `double` value.

You can see the differences in the following example:

```
double d = 1.5;

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("pt-PT");
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString());            // 1,5
Console.WriteLine(XmlConvert.ToString(d));  // 1.5

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");

Console.WriteLine(d.ToString());            // 1.5
Console.WriteLine(XmlConvert.ToString(d));  // 1.5
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did not find these from Microsoft's documentation.